# How do I get a discord user's profile picture?

Tags: javascript, discord

I am just curious (and might need it for later), If I wanted a discord user's pfp for my website, then how could I do that **WITH** discord API but **NOT** discord.js?

Comment: As per Discord Docs: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user (you will still need a bot token)

Comment: No, not at all, that didn't help me (I couldn't understand what's in there)

Comment: I found a [better post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450055/how-to-get-avatar-from-discord-api), sorry for wasting your time here!